# How do i remove friend from manytomany field

Tags: python, django

I am working on a dating website using Django, where i can add and remove friend. I have a little complication on how i can remove/unfriend a user i added. With the code i tried, i get this erro "Cannot query "oghomwenoguns": Must be "Profile" instance."

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=True,blank=True) 
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePicture/', default="ProfilePicture/user-img.png", blank=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null= True)  

def delete_friend_request(request, id):
    my_friend = get_object_or_404(User,id=id)
    frequest = Profile.objects.filter(friends=my_friend)
    frequest.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

<a href="{% url 'site:delete_friend_request' u.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg waves-effect font-weight-bold text-capitalize ml-0 mt-2" style="font-size:14px;padding:10px;width:40%;">Unfriend</a>
```

Comment: You want to remove `my_friend` from `request.user.friends` ?

Comment: @John... yes. my_friend is an id to the user i want to remove. trying to do that i get this message "Cannot query "oghomwenoguns": Must be "Profile" instance." where "oghomwenoguns" is my_friend. How can i remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to remove the friend `my_friend` from `request.user.friends`.

It would be something like this:

```
def delete_friend_request(request, id):
    user_profile = request.user.profile
    friend_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=id) # Profile instance has the same id as user
    user_profile.friends.remove(friend_profile) # A removes B
    friend_profile.friends.remove(user_profile) # B removes A
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

You just need to remove it from the `friends` list, not delete the user instance.

**Note:** Make sure all `User` instances has a `Profile`.

You can update current isntances using this command sequence:

```
python manage.py shell

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from app_name.models import * # app_name must be the name of your application

user_with_no_profile = User.objects.filter(profile__isnull=True)

for u in user_with_no_profile:
  u.profile = Profile()
  u.save()
```

Seeing your example, be sure to paint the html as follows, so only the id of the user's friends will appear.

```
{% for u in request.user.friends.all %}
   <a href="{% url 'site:delete_friend_request' u.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg waves-effect font-weight-bold text-capitalize ml-0 mt-2" style="font-size:14px;padding:10px;width:40%;">Unfriend</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDITED:** Now both friends are removed.

Comment: @John..thank you. i think this worked. but when i click on the link i get page not found 404

Comment: @GistDomBlog Make sure that all `user` instances have a `profile` instance created

Comment: i do not understand, i am new on django. is there a way you could make me understand how to make sure that all user instance have a profile instance created. I was able to complete add to friend and accept friend request.

Comment: I was able to remove friends from list, but the problem is that if two user becomes friends, when A remove/unfriend B, B is still a friend to A. How do I remove both friendship from manytomany field? I mean, when A remove/unfriend B, A and B will no longer be friends.

Comment: @GistDomBlog Now both friends are removed.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the problem following your code. I have just one problem concerning another code. How do I get the ID of a particular user without passing a primary key? I tried user=request.user.id and user=request.user but not gets the ID of the user I send a request to on the homepage.

Comment: @GistDomBlog You have to filter through [`Users.objects.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)